# response redirect not working on localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am currently debugging my application on localhost and i have this line below which redirects to another page.

```
 var redirectUrl = string.Format("../MyPage/TestPage.aspx?TicketNo=" + TicketNo);
 Response.Redirect(redirectUrl, true);
```

But this is not working on my local environment while debugging. It works on production environment. I am not even getting proper exceptions. I see its throwing system.threading.ThreadAbortion

What can i do to get it resolved?

Comment: Please check the proper path in this line : string.Format("../MyPage/TestPage.aspx?TicketNo=" + TicketNo);

Comment: Check the remarks on the msdn doc, it mentions the ThreadAbortException. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Maybe use Server.MapPath to get the right path instead of relying on hard-coded relative paths

Comment: But does it redirect? And you can prevent those exceptions by setting the boolean to `false` (not ending the response). But then all code below the redirect will be executed also.

Comment: The proper way to redirect is to use overload with `false` and then do: `HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();`

Comment: @Crowcoder this works :)

Comment: @Crowcoder this removes querystring when its redirected

Comment: Is that really the code you are running? `String.Format` takes more than one argument.

Comment: @Crowcoder yes thats the code i run

Comment: I really don't think it removes the query string. Run a trace in your browser dev tools and look at the traffic to see what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
 var redirectUrl 
     = string.Format("~/MyPage/TestPage.aspx?TicketNo=" + TicketNo);
 Response.Redirect(redirectUrl, false);
```

Note, I don't think you need the String.Format method here. It will compile and run but does nothing, presuming TicketNo is already a string.

Answer (score 0):

As @Crowcoder stated this worked for me.

> Response.Redirect("URL", false);
>   HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();